# Android splash screen and async

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, sdk, splash-screen

When creating a splash screen for an Android app, does the code that runs while the splash screen is visible need to be asynchronous?  If so, why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, otherwise your splash image will never show until the code completes. Because Android has the single UI thread. If you do anything else in that UI thread then no UI changes are possible until your other code finishes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all the code in onStart needs to finish before the UI defined in the layout for the activity will appear?